# What is the probability that you will get at least one matching suit in 4 draws without replacement from a standard deck of cards?

Tags: statistics

I was wondering if someone could help me out with this one. I missed the lecture for this topic and am struggling to catch up. Could someone possibly explain this one to me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most discrete probability problems like this are done by counting:

Count the number of ways you can draw 4 cards where at least two of them are the same suit.

Divide by the total number of ways you can draw 4 cards. This is $52\choose 4$.

An easier way to do it is to realize this is the complement of drawing 4 cards each of a different suit. There are $13^4$ ways to do this.

So the probability you want is $$1-\frac{13^4}{52\choose 4} \approx 89.45\%$$

If you wanted to count directly the number of ways to draw at least 2 cards of the same suit (which would be a good exercise in avoiding double counting), the answer to check with is ${52\choose 4} - 13^4$ since it is the complement of the event described above.